# Why doesn't this SVG file work in IE9/10?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

I have created sever svg files (using Illustrator) that basically have a rectangle filled with a pattern for use on a website.  The issue is that the SVG files work properly in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but fail to show the pattern in IE 9/10.

I seem to have narrowed the issue down to the viewbox attribute that is set on the pattern element.  I believe that IE doesn't like the negative numbers in the viewbox.

Any ideas on how this file could be fixed? Maybe how to re-calculate the polygon coordinates if I reset the viewbox attribute to non-negative numbers?

http://armadillo-co.com/assets/hexagon.svg

Comment: I can open it with IE 9.0.8112.16421 and it's same as in Chrome

Comment: Yes, I found a fix and uploaded a new version.  Thanks for looking.  I was able to copy the pattern into a new svg file, open that file in inkscape and edit the pattern so that it started at the 0 0 mark.  Then I copied over the new pattern elements to the old file and reset the viebox to 0 0 width height.